# Upgrading Angular v8 to Angular v9 get "ngx-mat-select-search" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/material"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular8, angular9

I m  trying to upgrade from angular 8 to Angular 9 using [Documentation](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l3)

When I run `ng update @angular/material` I get this error

```
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "ngx-mat-select-search" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/material" (requires "^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0", would install "9.1.3").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
```

My package.json current ngx-mat-select-search versionn is 1.8.0

Can someone please advise what to do without using --force whith ng update ?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "^9.0.7",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^1.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^12.3.1",
    "@material/list": "^3.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^3.4.5",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^7.2.0",
    "app": ">=0.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
    "flag-icon-css": "^3.4.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.2.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^1.8.0",
    "npm": "^6.11.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^9.0.7",
    "@types/escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5"
  }
```

Comment: Sounds pretty clear to me? `ngx-mat-select-search` 1.8.* is not compatible with angular 9, so you'll have to update it, too, if you want to keep using it (the current version for it is 2.1.2, with angular 8/9 compatibility, having dropped support for 5, 6, and 7)

Comment: Thank you Mike for your solution  ( ng update ngx-mat-select-search ) :)